# How to Index files on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**TLDR; Is there a keyboard shortcut or a command to index the whole project in android studio**

I noticed some drawable resources were still unresolved when I copied them in the `res/drawable` folder in android studio.

[image: 1]

I did a `File > Sync with File System` thinking that would resolve the issue.

But it didn't solve it as they were still unresolved.
The build is successful and the app runs but the IDE is not happy for some reason.

It works when I restart android studio but I don't want to restart it every time I add an asset.

As android studio indexes the files sometimes saying 'indexing files' at the bottom. So I searched for it and there doesn't seem to be a keyboard shortcut.

Another issue:

The image assets get added as `filename (v24)`. Why is that?

Comment: I was able to know why v24. It's copying in the `drawable-v24` directory when I dragged and dropped the images in the `drawable` directory.

Comment: check in which exactly directory are the files placed

Comment: I moved them all to the drawable directory. I just need to know the keyboard shortcut

Comment: I don;t believe it is the indexing problem, but you can re-import the project, or use file-invalidate caches/restart

Comment: As I mentioned I know restart works. It's the first thing I tried. And it did work. But I'd like to know is there a way that doesn't require a restart?

Comment: try re-syncing gradle project - go to gradle tab, right-click there and resync

Comment: v24 stands for api 24. if you are coding something that only available from api 24, then android studio will ask you to create a v24 file. if you proceed it will create v24 file automatically without deleting your old file.